# c++ error "Braces around scalar initializer for type int*"

Tags: c++

Error: braces around scalar initializer for type int*

I'm trying to pass an array to the function but I keep getting this error in the initialization step.

How can I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void func (int *p[4]);
int main()
{
int *p[4]={ {1,4,5},{3,5,6},{6,6,2},{6,5,3}};   //The error appears here                                                                   
func(p);
return 0;
}
void func (int *p[4])
{
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
for(int j=0;j<1;j++)
{  cout<<p[i][j]; }
}
cout<<" \t";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is what is `p`.

Whit this definition:

```
int *p[4];
```

this is 4 element array of pointers to `int`.
I guessing you wanted this:

```
int (*p)[3];
```

pointer to 3 element array of `int`s.
Also to use initialization you need an array.

Here is [working example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FaZhFwchICjmQ2AE).

Answer (score 2):

The variable `p` is an array of *pointers*. `{ 1, 4, 5 }` is *not* a pointer.

You need to make `p` an array of *arrays*:

```
int p[4][3] = { ... };
```

Because of that change, you have to change the `func` function argument as well, as `p` will now decay to a pointer to an array, of type `int (*)[3]` (that is, the argument for `func` should be `int (*p)[3]`).

Answer (score 1):

This would work, however you are going to lose array information because they will [decay into pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying):

```
int arr1[] = { 1,4,5 };
int arr2[] = { 3,5,6 };
int arr3[] = { 6,6,2 };
int arr4[] = { 6,5,3 };

int *p[4] = { arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4 };
```

Comment: @PasserBy why? This is another way to fix it. Not pretty, but correct.

Comment: @MarekR Not pretty is bad enough on its own, it is harder to read and is pretty much undoable once the array size got bigger. Other problems include it throwing away type information on the arrays, not stating the arrays should be uniform in size, potentially wrecking your cache as the arrays may or may not be contiguous, and having another chance for pointers to dangle. Why would you not use multidimensional arrays? Would _you_ let this pass in a code review?

Comment: all this doesn't make it incorrect, but ugly and not optimal.

Comment: @MarekR I didn't argue about its correctness. As an answer, I expect it to be at least neutral on the badness scale, you are after all, suggesting people do this.

Comment: @Passer By Thank you for your comment, however for all we know this is what OP wanted, array of 4 pointers, just didn't know how to construct it. The function argument and content suggest that array decaying is not a problem in this case. However, I have added warning to the answer to make you happy.